# Using FFMPEG and url_fopen example

Tags: c++, c, streaming, ffmpeg, live

I wonder how to get a stream from a URL (with [`url_fopen`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/group__old__url__f__funcs.html#g6db7660f3f798193d0d72447894f9932) for example) (live video or PCM stream for example) and encode it into something?

***Update:***
This actually was a mall formated question. It was about how to stream something out using url_fopen.

***Answer:***
It is quite simple:
There is like [a short article explaining how to use it](http://wiki.aasimon.org/doku.php?id=ffmpeg:url_fopen)
And I had a small video streaming solution which actually used it and [`url_write`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avio_8c.html#57f591eaf6c86d82cbe362b9cfd81225) called [HelloVideoStreaming (windows sln)](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/detail?r=678#) some many revisions ago.

Good thing is that you actually do not really need or want to use ffmpeg for streaming. But you want to have sendable packets of encoded data in order to send. [We have a client that does it (crossplatform, with premake project generation script)](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/?r=1122#svn/trunk/CloudClient). Main thing there is to use   [`url_open_dyn_buf`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avio_8h.html#53d2aad92a48effe20665b597a5e4dff) and [`url_close_dyn_buf`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avio_8h.html#34f67789f551d0f42c4394309529be91) which are shortly described [here](http://lab.dyne.org/Ffmpeg/UseUrlProtocol)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a stream and play it or store it using C++, you should simply use, for example, live555 library. It's a big lib which do the dirty job for you and provide a nice interface.